# Filter pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm trying to filter a pandas pivot table, but am not sure of the correct syntax to filter the "group by" arguments. I've been trying the standard `df['column_name']` but I receive a KeyError.

Here's the code for the table

`pivot = pd.pivot_table(q5,values='ENTRIES',index('DATE','STATION','ID'),aggfunc='sum')`

Here is what my pivot table looks like:

```
                                     ENTRIES
DATE         STATION       ID         
1/1/13         1 AVE        1          12
                            2          60
                            3          0
                            4          111
                            5          123
...
```

The desired result is to return Dates and Stations where at least one ID had < 10 Entries, but not all IDs had <10 Entries

Thanks

Comment: Please replace your image by textual data. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What will be the desired result?

Comment: Something like `pivot[pivot['ENTRIES'] < 10]` ?

Comment: @KarnKumar That looks good, but I would like to return all IDs associated with the Station, not just the ID that is 0

Comment: Can you  try `pivot[pivot['ENTRIES'] < 10]   ! = 0`

Comment: @KarnKumar Just returns "False" instead of 0s

Comment: Correct it will return Boolean values , try this to get the actual values `pivot[pivot[pivot['ENTRIES'] < 10].ne(0)].dropna()`  , however in your sample data i do not see values less than 10 except zero .